# What is the network role of this Raspberry Pi in the network schema?

Tags: networking

Before doing research on how to configure the Raspberry Pi, I need some help knowing what the role of the Raspberry Pi, in this set up, is called.

[image: network schema]

I suspect its this one;
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md.
But it might also be something like this; https://medium.com/@edoardo849/turn-a-raspberrypi-3-into-a-wifi-router-hotspot-41b03500080e

*Note: In the network schema, the rest of the network users are connected by WiFi.*

Comment: To answer with any certainty, we'd need to know where the figure came from. If this is a design concept, it can likely be improved significantly.

Comment: Expanding on the comment by @bobstro, the figure does not tell us what role the Pi is playing.  We'd have to guess.

Comment: I did the figure myself. Please be free to update how you see fit, this link gives edit access; https://goo.gl/ykZvFh. The purpose of the Pi is to connect the Ethernet Hub to the same network that the WiFi Router supplies. As the Pi has both Ethernet and WiFi network capabilities I thought it might do the job. Performance is not very important in this case.

Comment: I did it in https://www.draw.io. To bad the link does only view the image. I tried to get a link to draw.io with the document editable. But does not seem to work public but only to specified users. At least when storing it in Google Drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pi in this diagram is being used as a **Wireless Bridge** to connect the wireless network to the wired network containing the NAS.

A bridge is a device which (almost seamlessly) joins segments of network which may be different physical or low-level protocols (802.3 for wired and 802.11 for wireless.)   If it offered up an SSID for wireless clients to connect to directly then it would be an *Access Point*.

Because of the relatively slow performance of the Pi's Ethernet port (up to 100mb) it would probably be better to purchase another wifi router (which will handle better throughput) and configure this as a bridge.

Comment: Presumably the users are connecting to the Wifi Router at the right. Perhaps it's intended as a wifi range extender? The RPi is definitely a bottleneck as shown. That's not how I'd connect my users to a NAS.

Comment: @bobstro; Good feedback. It was thought for home usage. But I think a Linksys E1200 with DD-WRT might be better. But then is the new question, should it be configured at as a WiFi range extender or Wireless Bridge?

Comment: A "range extender" is typically referring to a wifi-wifi bridge. A "wireless bridge" is usually, though not always, referring to a wired-wifi bridge. The terms have specific meanings, but marketeers like to misuse them. To be pedantic, it could be a router, but a bridge makes sense.

Comment: @Tim - Pretty much any soho router like the Linksys can be configured as a bridge or as a range extender.  Unless you're having severe signal issues then the fewer access points the better.

Comment: I ended up using a Linksys E1200 (v2), installed with DD-WRT and configured as a wireless bridge following these guides; [E1200v2](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_E1200v2) and [Wireless Bridge](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge). It all seems to work well.